# My converted .ogv (html5) video is downloaded in several requests not a single request, what is causing this?

Tags: html, html5-video, ogg

I am seeing, in firebug, that my .ogv video(770KB) is being downloaded in several partial content requests while if I replace this with another video(1.7 MB) that I got from somewhere else then this is downloaded always in a single request.

What may be causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just firefox trying to be smart. I would not worry about it. 
By reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=502894#c1 I think firefox first start downloading the file, then if it finds the file header doesn't contain the duration of the movie, it downloads the last part of the file, which contains the timestamp of the last frame, after that it will continue downloading where it stopped at the beginning of the file.

My guess is the other file has the duration coded in the header somehow, or, if you are hotlinking it from some other server, that the other server is not supporting http-ranges